# how to use tagDEC (DECIMAL type) in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, decimal

I use an API that returns a windows DECIMAL type.

I need to convert it, the information I need is:

- the number of decimal place
- the value itself

For example, if my number is 1.234, I would like to get (3, 1234), for 10 (0,10) for 0.01 (2,1).
How can I extract this information from the tagDec object ?

Thanks

Comment: What in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221061.aspx don't you understand?

Comment: Guessing, but that unnamed struct is unusual.

Comment: What's with the `_MAC` conditional? Is that really how MS thinks of endianess? Not looking to hot now that Macs run on x86!

Comment: @David Heffernan: it's a leftover from Office for Mac OS 9. That had to fake COM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given `DECIMAL d`, the number of decimal places is `d.scale` and the value is `(d.sign?-1:1) * (double(d.Lo64) + double(d.Hi32) * double(1UL<<32) * double(1UL<<32)) * pow(10, d.scale)`

Comment: Given DECIMAL d, the number of decimal places is d.scale and the value is ((d.sign & DECIMAL_NEG) ? (-1.0) : 1.0) * (double(d.Lo64) + double(d.Hi32) * double(1UL<<32) * double(1UL<<32)) * pow(10.0, -d.scale)